# What is the best way to create shaped/polygonal buttons in c# and asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics, medical

I'm building a medical application for work and i wanted to use an image of a human anatomy and make some parts clickable. For example if there is a fracture in the tibia, i want to make that region glow red and if the user wants to record an injury, they can click on the affected regions and that will create a post-back which will record the area clicked.

But i am not sure which route to take. I researched a bit and found that i can trace shape paths in Illustrator and send the vectors inside Microsoft Blend and there i can build it in xaml/silverlight. I tried it but i dont like it because firstly, the future of Silverlight is very bleak and secondly it wont work on iPads or non silverlight-compatible devices.

Is there another option i should look into, maybe some advanced canvas features? My goal is to make this happen in .net 3.5 if possible.

[image: Example of background image]

Comment: `SVG` would be your best bet. You can export Illustrator files as svg's and they are iPad friendly btw

Comment: I will look into SVG. I've used SVG for d3.js so im familiar with that but i'm not sure i know how to connect a postback from javascript into C#/Asp.net

Comment: You can attach click events to your SVG polygons via javascript and have them trigger a postback if you wish

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it.